# Get command string within ZSH completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

`Given the following completion:

```
$ cat _anssh
#compdef anssh

_anssh () {
    _arguments '-i[inventory file]:filename:->files'
    case "$state" in
        files)
            _anssh_inventories_show
            ;;
        *)
            _anssh_hosts_show
            ;;
    esac
}

_anssh_inventories_show () {
    local -a inventories
    inventories=("${(@f)$(find hosts -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf 'hosts/%f\n')}")
    _multi_parts / inventories
}

_anssh_hosts_show () {
    local inv=$(echo $@ | sed 's/.*\-i\s*//g' | awk '{print $1}')
    local invflag=""
    if [ "$inv" != "" ]; then
        invflag="--inventory $inv"
    fi
    local hosts=("${(s/ /)$(anssh $invflag -l)}")
    _values 'hosts' $hosts
}
```

The part that does not work is that `_anssh_host_show` should return different values depending on how `-i` is defined (if it is defined). I try to extract the value of `-i` from `$@` (which I expect to be the full command entered so far), but `$@` is empty in context of the completion. How do I get that string instead?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
#compdef anssh

local -a command

_anssh () {
    command="$words"
    _arguments '-i[inventory file]:filename:->files'
    case "$state" in
        files)
            _anssh_inventories_show
            ;;
        *)
            _anssh_hosts_show
            ;;
    esac
}

_anssh_inventories_show () {
    local -a inventories
    inventories=("${(@f)$(find hosts -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf 'hosts/%f\n')}")
    _multi_parts / inventories
}

_anssh_hosts_show () {
    local inv=$(echo $command | grep ' -i' | sed 's/.*\-i\s*//g' | awk '{print $1}')
    local invflag=""
    if [ "$inv" != "" ]; then
        invflag="-i $inv"
    fi
    local hosts=("${(s/ /)$(anssh $invflag -l)}")
    _values 'hosts' $hosts
}

_anssh
```